# Using hook_civicrm_tabset; why doesn't my tab focus when linked to via url?

Tags: extension, hooks

I've added a tab adjacent to the event "Info and Settings" configuration tab, using hook_civicrm_tabset(), but when I link to the URL for that tab, the "Info and Settings" tab is displayed. This behavior is different from that of native tabs, such as "Location": I can type in the URL for that tab, and the tab is correctly selected.

**Question:** How can I get my "My Settings" tab to display itself from a URL in a way that's equivalent to the behavior of native tabs such as Location?

---

Here are some examples of native URLs that work as expected, and my custom tab which does not.

**"Info and Settings" tab**
http://example.l/civicrm/event/manage/settings?reset=1&action=update&id=23

[image]

---

**"Location" tab**
http://example.l/civicrm/event/manage/location?reset=1&action=update&id=23

[image]

---

**"My Settings" tab**
http://example.l/civicrm/event/manage/mysettings?reset=1&action=update&id=23

[image]

---

Example code (slightly redacted for public viewing)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_tabset().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tabset/
 */
function myextension_civicrm_tabset($tabsetName, &$tabs, $context) {
  if ($tabsetName == 'civicrm/event/manage') {
    if ($eventId = CRM_Utils_Array::value('event_id', $context)) {
      $tab['mysettings'] = array(
        'title' => E::ts('My Settings'),
        'link' => NULL, // 'link' is automatically provided if we're under the 'civicrm/event/manage' path.
        'class' => 'ajaxForm', // allows form to re-load itself on save.
        'valid' => _myextension_EventHasMySettings($eventId), // indicates whether tab has actively used settings.
        'active' => TRUE,
        'current' => FALSE, // setting this to FALSE prevents the tab from pre-loading
                            // focus when the page is loaded.
      );
    }
    else {
      $tab['mysettings'] = array(
        'title' => E::ts('My Settings'),
        'url' => 'civicrm/event/manage/mysettings',
        'field' => 'is_my_settings',
      );
    }
    //Insert this tab into position 1
    $tabs = array_merge(
      array_slice($tabs, 0, 1),
      $tab,
      array_slice($tabs, 1)
    );
  }

  // Set mysettings tab as enabled/disabled in configuration popup-menu, on manage events listing screen.
  if ($tabsetName == 'civicrm/event/manage/rows' && $eventId = CRM_Utils_Array::value('event_id', $context)) {
    $tabs[$eventId]['is_my_settings'] = _myextension_EventHasMySettings($eventId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add below line in your preprocess() function.

```
$this->assign('selectedChild', 'mysettings');
```

Comment: I don't have a preprocess hook implementation at this point. But I added that assign() statement to the buildQuickForm() method of my CRM_Myextension_Form_Event_Mysettings() form class (the class that's mapped to this tab URL in the menu xml), and that does the trick. I'm guessing that's essentially what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i meant function not hook, it can either go in preprocess or buildquickform function of your form class.

Comment: So are you happy to mark this is as answered?

Comment: With the edit, yes. Thanks!